# adding a python node that uses opencv - ROS Indigo

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this guide http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/
for setting up OpenCV for ROS Indigo (since it doesn't come bundled anymore).

Now, the problem is I don't have an executable node that is produced from a CPP source file for `target_link_libraries` but I have a python node that uses OpenCV.

After adding
1)

all the dependencies in "package.xml" file,

and 2)

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

in the  CMakeLists.txt file, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at HELLO_WORLD/CMakeLists.txt:168 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "HELLO_WORLD" which is not built
  by this project.
```

How do I resolve this issue?
Other nodes written in Python, I can just say "rosrun [PACKAGE_NAME] python_node.py"
But in this Python node that uses OpenCV, I need to make changes appropriately in the CMakeLists.txt file. Only, I'm not quite sure what it is. sources I've referred to talk about CPP nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207654/adding-a-python-node-that-uses-opencv---ros-indigo/) by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2015-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're only using OpenCV with python, you don't need to add anything in your CMakeLists.txt. As long as the python module is on your PYTHONPATH, you're all set.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2015-04-23**:
Thanks! Yes, I realised that "import cv2" already exists in the code.
And it was pointed about by another gentleman on another post as well but this makes it clear :)